# How to update commit message in case of `--no-verify`?

Tags: git, githooks

We have written pre-commit hooks for our git repository. But, developers can use `--no-verify` to bypass the pre-commit hooks, and commit anyways. I was wondering, if git provides some way to update the commit message when the `--no-verify` flag is present to maybe add `Not Hook Verified:` in such commit messages? Or some other check that can be added for this scenario?

Comment: you could take the opposite approach and *add* something when the hooks have not been skipped

Answer (score 1):

Unless you're willing to fork git, modify behavior of `--no-verify`,
distribute modified git binary around and somehow convince everyone to
use it it's not possible to prevent users from doing `git commit --no-verify` and add some arbitrary words to the commit message.
Consider setting up a continuous integration server that will always
run the checks when it receives a pull/merge request, it cannot
bypassed as it's run on the server.

Answer (score 0):

If your goal is to update the commit message itself, such as to automatically include a JIRA ID or such, you can use the `prepare-commit-msg` hook to modify the commit message before the editor is started.  The developer of course may modify that message, but I've personally found it helpful for cases like the one mentioned above.

If your goal is to rat out the developers who use `git commit --no-verify`, then, no, there isn't a way to do that.  If your goal is to implement a policy for code, then that change either belongs in a `pre-receive` hook or in your CI system.  You cannot trust that anything will run on a developer system because the developer could modify it or delete it.

In addition, implementing `pre-commit` hooks for testing or checking items is a problem because it makes it harder and less convenient for people to make small fixup commits that they then squash together.  For example, I often commit a `WIP` change when I have a small, logical piece that works and then I can roll back if I break things.  When I'm ready to submit, I squash these together into a logical change.  I know full well that such commits won't meet commit message standards or pass all the tests, but they are extremely useful for temporary purposes.